# Failed to get Browser name through Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am executing following code in apex class which is a controller for one of my visualforce pages.

`String userAgent = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('User-Agent');`
`System.debug('userAgent:'+userAgent);`

This code returns following:

***On Chrome:***
`userAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

***On Safari:***
`userAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.4 Safari/605.1.15`

I am using Macbook to run this code.

Is there a way to get the browser Name in apex class?

Comment: May I know what's the whole scenario where you need the browser name?

Comment: @jaiaswani10 i have <apex:repeat> in visualforce component. If the browser is Safari then only I want to show  button.

Answer (score 0):

Try Querying on LoginHistory Object
SELECT Browser, Platform, Application, LoginTime, LoginType, Status from LoginHistory

all users can retrieve their own login history records.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm